# Tips for avoiding floor impact noise

Tags: flooring, code-compliance, joists, subfloor, noise-reduction

We had a 2-story extension built, complies with earthquake code in Oregon. It only has a sub-floor right now but the impact noise from the bedroom to the kitchen downstairs is shocking.

The final flooring will be engineered wood planks. We are putting down noise-impact underlayment with an IIC of 72, but we would have happily paid for a stronger construction.

Comment: Please [edit] this to actually be a question. That's the way the site works.

Comment: "*but we would have happily paid for a stronger construction.*" Thank You for  let us know. Is there a question that  you meant to ask?

Comment: learn to step lightly

Comment: Wearing soft footwear and learning to walk quietly - I weigh over 100kg but make less noise than some females who only weigh about half what I do...

Comment: @jsotola and if the new bedroom was built to give their kid more room  for martial arts practice (or anything other than sitting/lying/tiptoeing)?

Answer (score 1):

Tip: speak to your contractor about spacing the joists closer together and put in blocking. Or anything else to reduce impact noise. The code is not good enough!!

Comment: accoustic insulation in the ceiling and thicker plaster may help too.